# Vertically centered text, in 8 item justified, fluid width menu in 2 rows and gutters

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, justify

I'm creating an 8 item justified, fluid width menu in 2 rows with centered text and gutters.

This means 4 items per row with approximately 24% width. Gutters are transparent.
Everything is in place except for centering long menu texts that wraps. As soon as the text wraps, the second text-row "falls" beneath the menu item.

**How do I set some kind of line-height for the menu item so that longer texts gets wrapped but still are vertically centered?**

I'm using pseudo elements on both ul and li tags, but if there are better solutions (including javascrip) I'm open for it. No menu item i s longer than 2 lines and the menu will have mobile menu solution for smaller screens. Ordinary browser support and IE8+

HTML is generated by WordPress so can't change to much there.

Code, image and fiddle below.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul >
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Longer text Longer text Longer text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Normal text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: grey;
}

ul {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.1px;
}

ul:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

li {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: the menu]

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/A347a/

Comment: I should add that the HTML, in this case, is generated bt WordPress. So there's not to much I can alter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a structure I would use a table, way more handy:

HTML

```
<table id="wrapper">
    <tbody >
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">longer text longer text longer text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">Normal text</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    col {
        max-width: 250px;
    }
    background: grey;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tbody {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.1px;
}


td {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A347a/2/)

Comment: Thanks. The HTML is in this case generated by WordPress, so I can't do much about that.

Comment: I see. Overflow scrollable could do or everything should be displayed? Scrollable: http://jsfiddle.net/A347a/3/

Comment: No menu texts are longer than 2 rows if that's what you mean?

Comment: No what I mean is that without scroll option, your height/length of text problem is always gonna be there as the li are independent, unlike table cells. Which means that if one is bigger, the others are not gonna change height. So you have to choose between fix height and scroll method, or re-structure the html -which should be possible in wp-

Comment: Ah ok. The height should be fixed and think it is in my fiddle.

Comment: What generate your lines to be off like that is your after element, which basically act like a line-height. So I would get rid of it first.

Comment: Basically you need to alter the html to best solve your problem, or go for a scroll overflow option. What can you change on your html?

Comment: The after element is for the justify function and comes from http://goo.gl/ukIsOj. The before element is for align middle and comes from http://goo.gl/s7vASl. Removing the before fixes the "off line" but then I need other solution to align middle.

Comment: Which is why I asked what can you modify in your html, what can't you?

Comment: Well, the menu output fron WordPress is kinda built around the concept of ul and li. Can probably add classes, spans on the fly.

Comment: Think I solved this with some small additions @thomasstephn's http://jsfiddle.net/A347a/3/ . Be back with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the height definition on the a:before element. I don't know of a good way to solve this problem with css only. Either you take care, that the content does not get longer than one line and use the current code or possibly try some js-magic that changes the DOM if content above a certain text length is detected.